# Equivalent of SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, autonumber

As the title suggests, is there any way of turning off an autonumber field in Access to allow me to insert a row with an id of my choosing, such as you would do with SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF in SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert an ID with SQL.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID) Values (-10)
```

Comment: You know what, you're absolutely right, I was getting hooked on an error on the insert statement which I presumed the autonumber was causing the problem, however, just tried a simple insert and yes, you can easily add a row, now to go track down the error then!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The autonumber property sets a field's default value as the autonumber seed value.  If the autonumber field is also the primary key (or has a separate unique constraint), you can't re-use any of the stored values.  However, you can explicitly insert any long integer value which doesn't conflict with the existing stored values.  And without a unique constraint on the autonumber field you can insert the same value repeatedly.

You may not really even need the equivalent of SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF