# Autonumber - start from ZERO

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I know how to add an autonumber field to a table using SQL:

```
dblocal.Data.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & TableName & " (" & FieldName & " COUNTER(1,1) )"
```

Where dblocal is the passed database reference with TableName & FieldName the appropriate names for the desired creation of the table.

However, I want the counter to start at **ZERO** not **ONE**. And I know it's possible because the table I need to repair / duplicate starts with **ZERO**

What am I not finding on the internet to aid me in this task?
My search-fu fails me.

Comment: Why the `Excel` and `VBA` tags?

Comment: Why bother? (You shouldn't build applications depending on a specific value.)

Comment: If it were possible (not sure, haven't tried it) then I would assume that `COUNTER(1,1)` should be `COUNTER(0,1)`

Comment: Tested and works. Also wonder why needed.

Comment: The primary key / ID of a record should have no meaning whatsoever - as such its value is utterly irrelevant, or *should* be. Consider separating concerns and making whatever value you have that has a semantic meaning in your application, NOT be the table's primary key (assuming there *is* a primary key - that's typically what autonumber columns are used for)

Comment: Also it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691253/equivalent-of-set-identity-insert-off-in-access) Access lets you insert IDs without a fuss, so if the reason is migration of existing data... the identity seed isn't really relevant then.